# Marionette multiple regionTypes

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a custom region for my main application that allows me to do page transitions. This works for one style of transition, but how would I go about creating different transitions for this region.

Can we set multiple regionTypes on the same region, or would I have to pass the transition type to my modified Marionette region show function and go from there. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
        App.addRegions {
            main: {
                selector: "#page",
                regionType: Fold
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot associate multiple-types to the same region.
Your options become if the knowledge of knowing which way to render is the role of the region-manager or outside of it.

From your statement of passing the 'transition type' in, you are thinking that the responsibility of figuring out which transition to use is NOT the role for the region manager.

This question may be better answered base on your design.

Hope this help.